# How do I cancel a stale "pending" drive mount with error "An operation is already pending"

Tags: mount, luks, unmounting

The `An operation is already pending` error is very generic and many things can cause this. (other answers don't relate to my problem).

I have a Luks encrypted volume that I clicked to open, a password prompt appeared, and I waited too long to enter the password. (It normally works just fine.) Now, whenever I try to open it, I just get that error instead of the password prompt.

I'm sure rebooting the computer would fix it, but I don't want to do that... I'm sure it's just some sort of mount lock that needs to be manually released. How do I release the lock manually so I can try again?

The OS is Mate on Mint 17.3.

Answer (score 0):

Run htop from terminal or open your system monitor find the pid of the process in use and use the kill  command to stop the process.

Comment: also what method are you using to open the encrypted vol?

Comment: on mint it should be something like this "sudo cryptsetup -v luksOpen /dev/sdc1 sdc1crypt"  if you are using the terminal that is.